# Why my minted spl-token-2022 not coming up on phantom wallet?

Tags: spl-token, anchor-lang, token-2022, anchor-spl

I have created my spl-token-2022 from anchor smart contract but the minted tokens are not showing on my phantom wallet. What could be the possible reasons for this?

This is my token https://solscan.io/account/Hj9nivJnMoC9bGHdPxvVvWaH7UGgsNgkrXqhhbNhX3Zy

Comment: … the link you provided is in mainnet

Comment: But the mint account is on devnet

Answer (score 1):

This account has no data nor transaction history.

Is there a completed transaction signature or an explorer link?

Your link is not correct.

The mint is on devnet, you need to change the network inside phantom wallet.

Comment: It's an explorer link containing mint account address